How to do bind operation in ldap without explicitly using credentials (anonymous bind is not allowed)
I have built portal for my company and due to some requirement we need to query ldap server to fetch some details. However, I am not allowed to use/store any credentials for query ldap. Also the ldap server does not allows anonymous bind. is there any way to do bind operation and query ldap server.
My web server is running on linux system  and it is domain joined. In backend, I am  using python.


I am not allowed to use/store any credentials for query ldap. Also the ldap server does not allows anonymous bind.

Your requirements are contradictory. Either you bind with credentials or you bind without credentials – there is no third option.
It would be possible to use gss-proxy to store the credentials (Kerberos keytab) in a way that the application can use them, but cannot extract them – i.e. the keytab file is only accessible by root and the gss-proxy daemon acts like an agent similar to LSASS on Windows. It would be the safest option; however, the credentials still need to be stored somewhere on the system.
(Side note: gss-proxy is not the same as sssd's KCM. The latter only provides storage, but doesn't provide credential isolation.)
It would be possible to achieve something similar without gss-proxy, by using a kinit cron job (or the k5start tool – that runs as a different account, gets a TGT for the webapp, and chowns the ticket cache. That way again the webapp can use its 10-hour Kerberos ticket to query LDAP but has no access to the long-term credentials.
(The machine already has its own "machine credentials" stored on disk, i.e. machine keytab, which could in theory be used for this purpose; but that would be less secure, as it would allow the web app to impersonate the machine, so it's definitely not what you want. The app really ought to have its own set of credentials.)
It would also be possible to use Kerberos authentication for the web app itself (i.e. SPNEGO from web browser to app), and configure it to delegate the user's credentials to the webapp, so that the LDAP query could be made using the user's delegated credentials (which are only temporarily stored on disk). But delegation is insecure in its own ways – it means that instead of storing just one set of credentials permanently, the app now stores many sets temporarily and can impersonate every user, so the risk is larger again.

To use gss-proxy:

Create an AD service account for the webapp.

Create a keytab for the service account.

Verify that you can kinit with the keytab, and that the app can authenticate to LDAP using Kerberos (SASL GSSAPI bind); kdestroy after testing.
>>> import gssapi
>>> import os

# No tickets yet
>>> gssapi.Credentials(usage="initiate").name
gssapi.raw.exceptions.MissingCredentialsError

# Verify that the keytab is good
>>> os.system("kinit -k -t app.keytab")
>>> os.system("klist")
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_2001
Default principal: foo@EXAMPLE.COM

>>> gssapi.Credentials(usage="initiate").name
Name(b'foo@EXAMPLE.COM', <OID 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.1>)

>>> os.system("kdestroy")

To use Kerberos with LDAP:
serv = ldap3.Server("ldap://dc01.example.com")
conn = ldap3.Connection(serv,
                        authentication=ldap3.SASL,
                        sasl_mechanism="GSSAPI")
conn.bind()

The LDAP server must be specified by name, not by IP address.

Install gss-proxy.

Configure gss-proxy to let your app's system UID use the keytab as in the httpd example. Make sure to chown the keytab to a different user account (e.g. root) so that the app can no longer read it directly.
[service/myapp]
    mechs = krb5
    cred_store = ccache:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/krb5cc_%U
    cred_store = client_keytab:/etc/gssproxy/myapp.keytab
    euid = myapp


Run your app with GSS_USE_PROXY=1 in the environment. The GSSAPI library will automatically talk to gss-proxy instead of looking for a local ticket.
>>> import gssapi
>>> import os

# No tickets yet
>>> gssapi.Credentials(usage="initiate").name
gssapi.raw.exceptions.MissingCredentialsError

# Tell libgssapi to talk to the proxy
>>> os.environ["GSS_USE_PROXY"] = "1"

# Now it can see the tickets acquired by gss-proxy
>>> gssapi.Credentials(usage="initiate").name
Name(b'foo@EXAMPLE.COM', <OID 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.1>)




Considering gss-proxy is the safest. How can I do this in python. Could you please share reference  to it.

Which OS and which LDAP library are you using in Python?

OS  is Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.10 (Ootpa) and library is ldap3

Actually I can see gssproxy service is already running on the system. How Can I interact with it for the authentication ? I am just clueless here.
